# Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext error after upgrade jetty version to 9.4.44

Tags: jetty, apacheds

Current jetty version is 9.4.6, I tried to upgrade 9.4.44, I got the error. Could you please help me?

```
 WebAppContext:554 -Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@163f1cd{passwd-change,/passwd-change,file:///run/opt/corp/gsec/7.0.0/java-service/gsec-jetty-base/temp/jetty-gsec-2443-passwd-change.war-_passwd-change-any-6326268666909012254.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/passwd-change.war} 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$StaticContext.createInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; from class jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.newListenerInstance(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1945) ~[apacheds-service-2.0.0-M24.jar:2.0.0-M24] 
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1900) ~[apacheds-service-2.0.0-M24.jar:2.0.0-M24]
```

Comment: current jetty version is 9.4.6, I tried to upgrade 9.4.44, I got the error. Could you please help me?

Comment: It looks like you have an apacheds uber jar with jetty already included.  How did you upgrade Jetty?  details please.

Comment: I removed old jetty-disturbition-9.4.6.zip file and added new jetty-distrubition-94.44.zip file to my project . Whe I started jetty, I got this error:  Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jetty files in your `apacheds-service-2.0.0-M24.jar` needs to be upgraded as well.

List the contents of the `apacheds-service-2.0.0-M24.jar` file and you'll see classes in the `org.eclipse.jetty.` namespace.

Those are conflicting with your efforts to upgrade Jetty via the `jetty-distribution` zip.

Comment: Which apacheds version should I upgrade to?

Comment: i guess i should update it to  apacheds-2.0.0.AM26.zip

Comment: How can I build apacheds-server*.jar after all files under /org/eclipse/jetty/* changed with the files in the jetty-distrubition*.zip

Comment: Thanks Joakim, After changed the  /org/eclipse/jetty/* files in apacheds*.zip with  /org/eclipse/jetty/* files in jetty-distrubition*.zip, it is worked succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different setup that triggered a similar stacktrace: using `cargo-maven2-plugin 16.1` in a spring 5 project, `mvn cargo:run` would fail because of a conflict with `javafx.base-11.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` files.

Upgrading to [cargo-maven3-plugin](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven+3+Plugin.html) 1.9.9 fixed the matter.

I'd encourage who ever uses cargo-maven2-plugin to migrate to cargo-maven3-plugin as the doc states:

> Please be aware that the Maven 2 / Maven 3 plugin of Codehaus Cargo has been retired with our version 1.9.0 and has been superseded by a Maven 3 only plugin.